# GLIB_GSETTINGS not found while compiling gnome extension

Tags: compiling, gnome-shell

having failed to install a gnome extension from their website I looked for another way on Google. The guide I found was like:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-common
git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-shell-extensions
cd gnome-shell-extensions
./autogen.sh –prefix=$HOME/.local – enable-extensions=”dock”
```

The last command failed with the following error:

```
./configure: line 4276: GLIB_GSETTINGS: command not found
configure: error: invalid extension drop-down-terminal
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything helpful on Google this time.
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, gnome guys introduced an m4 macro in recent versions of `glib` - `GLIB_GSETTINGS` and distribute it with `glib` sources - [here it is in gsettings.m4](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/m4macros/gsettings.m4#n6): `AC_DEFUN([GLIB_GSETTINGS]...`.

Your package of interest, `gnome-extensions` makes use of this macro [at line 19 of configure.ac](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/tree/configure.ac?h=gnome-3-0#n19) and tries to search for it in standard system locations. Probably, you don't have glib sources installed, so it can't find it.

In Debian `gsettings.m4` comes in `libglib2.0-dev` package and is stored at `/usr/share/aclocal/gsettings.m4`. Install the dev package and build again.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. On ubuntu the package is named libglib2.0-dev though

Comment: Oh,my mistake. `libglib2.0-dev` on Debian, too. Glad it helped (I guess, you posted this question on like 5 different fora, according to google?).

Comment: Here and on askubuntu. Both questions aren't very popular so I cross-posted :(