# Not getting libglib2.0-dev (updated libraries) even after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.06

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, github

I wanted to compile and install something-for-reddit from git.

As I went with ./configure.ac it showed below error.

```
./configure: line 5088: GLIB_GSETTINGS: command not found
./configure: line 5089: syntax error near unexpected token `1.42.0'
./configure: line 5089: `GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_CHECK(1.42.0)'
```

As I searched here in stackoverflow, it showed me that the GLIB_GSETTINGS are found in libglib2.0-dev but as I tried to install it through

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0
```

Again it threw below error

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-refdbg' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil-dev' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-tests' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-dbg' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-bin' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dbg' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dev' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data' for regex 'libglib2.0'
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0' for regex 'libglib2.0'
libglib2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1).
libglib2.0-data is already the newest version (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1).
libglib2.0-bin is already the newest version (2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-0-dbg : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-0-refdbg : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4)
```

I have upgraded the system from 14.04 to 16.04 one month back, did I miss something or am I doing something wrong now .

The something for reddit git source is here. https://github.com/samdroid-apps/something-for-reddit 
You can check all the dependencies here too, [Package Details: something-for-reddit-git 0.1-1](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/something-for-reddit-git/)

Comment: Also found same errors faced by other users here..

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93688/glib-gsettings-not-found-while-compiling-gnome-extension

http://askubuntu.com/questions/354045/glib-gsettings-not-found-while-compiling-gnome-extension

Comment: I guess I can try for the next upgrade but 
how can I be sure, that I will not face same issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is Downgrade.

As I searched again in stackoverflow, I found the same issues is faced by others and they were suggested to downgrade the respective Library with following commands .

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0=2.48.0-1ubuntu4

sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Now I'm stuck with next issue, i.e. `./configure: line 5089`:`GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_CHECK(1.42.0)`'

Here is the link suggesting the downgrade : https://askubuntu.com/questions/58664/cant-install-package-libglib2-0-dev-because-it-depends-on-some-unknown-version/60314